# CMake not able to find Debug Library

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015

I am a CMake noob trying to put together a package installer so i can move between my windows development machine and my cluster.

I have the following directory tree for my files (an example)

```
    -Primary
       --Library Source
          --CMakeLists.txt
          --src1.cpp
          --src1.h
       --Application Source
          --CMakeLists.txt
          --src1.cpp
          --src1.h
       --CMakeLists.txt
```

Each CMakeLists.txt is 
Primary/CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(BloodVesselRadiationDamageSimulations CXX)

SET(FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS true)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}) #only for testing
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_ROOT}/ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP)
FIND_PACKAGE(MPI)
FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5)
FIND_PACKAGE(GTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")

SET(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX _d)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Source)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(SourceUnitTest)
```

Library Source/CMakeLists.txt

```
ADD_LIBRARY(VesselProjectBaseLibrary STATIC Src1.cpp 
                                            Src1.h) 
INSTALL(TARGETS VesselProjectBaseLibrary DESTINATION x64/Debug CONFIGURATIONS Debug)
INSTALL(TARGETS VesselProjectBaseLibrary DESTINATION x64/Release CONFIGURATIONS Release|RelWithDebInfo)
```

Application Source/CMakeLists.txt

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
ADD_EXECUTABLE (SourceUnitTests Src1.cpp
                                Src1.h)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SourceUnitTests ${GTEST_LIBRARY})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SourceUnitTests debug VesselProjectBaseLibrary_d optimized VesselProjectBaseLibrary)
```

I am able to generate the projects correctly; I see all the correct files in the projects. However, when i go to compile the debug build I get the following error:

```
1>ipo: : error #11018: Cannot open VesselProjectBaseLibrary_d.lib
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'VesselProjectBaseLibrary_d.lib'
```

If i compile my release build everything works perfectly and compilation is successful. The library compiles successfully under both builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link against a library *created within the project*, you need to specify library **target name**, not a library *file*. CMake will care about proper filename, path and other things:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SourceUnitTests VesselProjectBaseLibrary)
```

---

Variable `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` affects on library's *filename*. While file `VesselProjectBaseLibrary_d.lib` is actually created in debug build, it cannot be found automatically by the linker. Again, use target name and let CMake do all other work.